# How to include a project in a build that is not a dependency in Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build

I have two projects in my solution, A and B. A is the start-up project. B references A.

After making changes to both A and B when I start the solution A gets built, but not B. This makes sense since A does not reference B and A is the start-up project.

I would like both to build every time I start the solution. Currently I get round this problem by manually building B before running the solution.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure which projects can be built by changing the configuration available under the solution properties. Select "Solution" node and on right click, go to properties and try this. See if this works.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I checked, but all projects were already checked by default.